# Having trouble sending variables in functions as arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making simple program to get all the prime numbers in a range provided by the user. I get the input and I am attempting to send the lower bound and upper bound to a function. However, it keeps stating that the first parameter value is not used. The function is called `prime_checker`.

Strangely, I believe that the method I am using to send the variables over is correct as the second parameter is used. I tried using the same variables names (`lower_bound`) yet it does not function.

```
def prime_checker(lower, upper):
    x = 2
    flag = True
    for lower in range(upper):
        for x in range(lower):
            if lower % x == 0:
                flag = False
                x += 1
                lower += 1
            else:
                print(lower + "is a prime number.")
                x += 1
                lower += 1

lower_bound = int(input("Enter a lower bound: "))
upper_bound = int(input("Enter an upper bound: "))
prime_checker(lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

```
line 19, in <module>
    prime_checker(lower_bound, upper_bound)

line 8, in prime_checker
    if lower % x == 0:
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

```
Paramerer 'lower' is not used
```

Comment: `for lower in range(upper):` assigns to `lower` and overwrites it before the original value is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `for lower in range(upper):` assigns every value between zero (inclusive) and `upper` exclusive to the name `lower`. This discards the original value you pass in without ever using it. A corrected version would be

```
for lower in range(lower, upper + 1):
```

This takes care of iterating over the correct range.

Your inner loop has a couple of problems too. It starts at zero, which is the immediate cause of your error. You shouldn't start at one either, since divisibility by one is guaranteed. Instead, start with two:

```
for x in range(2, lower):
```

You definitely want to be exclusive on `lower`, since divisibility by that is guaranteed as well.

When `lower % x == 0`, you don't want to increment either variable, since the loops will overwrite any changes you make. Instead, you want to skip to the next iteration of `lower`, and start checking `x` from the beginning. This is accomplished by the `break` statement, which immediately exits the inner loop, and continues with the outer:

```
if lower % x == 0:
    break
```

Notice that just because a number is not divisible by 2, it is not necessarily prime. Your current `else` statement will declare `lower` prime for every value of `x` that isn't a divisor, regardless of whether `lower` is prime or not. The correct thing to do would be to report primeness only once, after checking all possible values of `x`.

Python happens to have a special version of the `else` clause that goes after a `for` loop, and only gets triggered when the loop completes without a `break`. So all you have to do is unindent your `else` one level, and of course don't pointlessly set loop variables.

The final result is something like this:

```
for lower in range(lower, upper + 1):
    for x in range(2, lower):
        if lower % x == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(f'{lower} is prime')
```

This is not a particularly efficient way to search for primes, but it illustrates how to fix the programming issues in your code.

Comment: Probably a different name to the loop variable that does not conflict with the parameter variable avoids confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much, I switched to a while loop and took in and corrected the existing problems with the code!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are doing `lower % x` when both `lower` and `x` are `0`. The value of `lower` and `x` is determined by the earlier lines `for .. in range(...)`, which in Python let you loop from `0` to the number you specify as parameter in `range()` minus one. Hence, exactly in the first iteration you have `0 % 0`, which is an undefined operation.

---

*EDIT*: That is not the only issue present in your code, e.g.:

- you are incrementing both `lower` and `x` explicitly, but this is actually taken care of by the `for` construction;
- you do some operations identically on both branches of the `if` and that's unnecessarily redundant;
- the algorithm is not really effective at checking for primality right now;
- your function always return `None` since it is missing an explicit use of `return`
- etc.

---

Along with what I believe is your train of thought, I would have probably written something like:

```
def give_primes(lower, upper):
    result = []
    for n in range(lower, upper):
        is_prime = True
        # check if `n` is prime
        # this could be heavily optimized
        for m in range(2, n):
            if n % m == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break
        if is_prime:
            result.append(n)
    return result


lower_bound = int(input("Enter a lower bound: "))
# you input: 10
upper_bound = int(input("Enter an upper bound: "))
# you input: 20

print(give_primes(lower_bound, upper_bound))
# [11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
```

This could be further improved, e.g. by using a separate `is_prime()` function (whose efficiency could be heavily improved compared to what is reported above, e.g. by checking `% 2` only once and then using `step=2` on the inner `range()`, stopping not when `m >= n` but when `m >= sqrt(n)`, etc.), using a generator instead of returning a list, etc.
but that would be too much meat for the grill of this question.